# How to write this equation in Latex? argmax

Tags: equations, subequations

How to write this kind of equation in Latex?

[image]

Comment: Not like your screenshot!

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}\DeclareMathOperator\argmax{argmax}` and then just write down the equation as you would for any other equation, but using `\argmax`.